# Inject condition in every query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Some of my models has a column named "company_id".

I need that all querys in these models has a condition based in this column, so I can easily separate the companies rows.

Something like this:

```
Customer.where(state: x).`where(company_id: current_company)`...
```

How can I intercept this method to enforce this extra condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a concern to add this requirement as a default scope to all of your models.

```
module HasCompany
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    default_scope { where(company_id: current_company) }
  end
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  include HasCompany
  ...
end
```

Note: this approach will only work if you have access to `current_company` as a class method on your models.

Answer (score 0):

Where does this code live? It looks like controller logic? If it's in a controller, then you can just set the `current_company` in a `before_action` in the application controller—probably like you're doing already. Presuming you have a `has_many` relationship between company and customers, you should just do `current_company.customers.where(state: x)`.

If this code lives in a model, that's when things get tricky. You shouldn't have access to `current_company` in a model, since that deals with the current request.

Comment: For an example: I need to get a discount list for a customer in one company. This same customer has discounts in another company, so I thought to put this logic in customer model.

Comment: If it *does* live in the model (and there's a lot of debate around whether it should), this is a decent pattern for having access to the `current` whatever: https://amitrmohanty.wordpress.com/2014/01/20/how-to-get-current_user-in-model-and-observer-rails/